# Change bar chart view angle / perspective

Tags: r, bar-chart

Recently I've been playing with an R package named [latticeExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latticeExtra/index.html) and created the following chart

[image: 3D Bar Chart]

with this code

```
library(latticeExtra)

heisenberg <- read.csv(file="ABSOLUTE_FILE_LOCATION")

x <- heisenberg[[1]]
y <- heisenberg[[2]]
z <- heisenberg[[3]]

cloud(z~x+y, heisenberg, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='green',
      xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4,scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1), 
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")))
```

I'm still not happy just by looking at the cube containing the chart from this angle / perspective.

Do you know how I can change the view angle to like the opposite side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the perspective, we use

```
screen = list(z = 0, x = 0, y = 0)
```

and change the values of z, x and y in accordance to what we want.

This code where *z = 90, x = -45, y=0*

```
library(latticeExtra)

heisenberg <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/tiago/Desktop/VIS/DATA/4/sample_1000.csv")

x <- heisenberg[[1]]
y <- heisenberg[[2]]
z <- heisenberg[[3]]

cloud(z~x+y, heisenberg, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='green',
      xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4,scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1),
      screen = list(z = 90, x = -45, y=0),
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")))
```

Gives this chart

[image: 3D Bar Chart with different perspective]